# How to find out which table/object the KEY or PAGE or EXTENT locks in the sys.dm_tran_locks belong to?

Tags: sql-server, locking, sql-server-2017

When I query `sys.dm_tran_locks`, a couple of questions arise:

1. I can see there are some locks that are placed at KEY, PAGE, EXTENT, RID level (`resource_type` column). How to find out to which table or object these particular keys, pages, extents, rids belong to?
2. For the OBJECT level locks (`resource_type = 'OBJECT'`) - what is the proper way to define object name? Is the `resource_associated_entity_id` column the `object_id` of the object? Or is there some caveat?
3. Some OBJECTS have `resource_associated_entity_id = -1261057897` (negative number) - how to find out the object name for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations()`](https://sqlity.net/en/2471/sys-dm_db_database_page_allocations/) was introduced specifically to avoid having to do any of this spelunking yourself, using unsupported and undocumented commands like `DBCC IND` and `DBCC PAGE`. I talk about [an even better replacement, coming in SQL Server 2019, in this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5714/new-function-in-sql-server-2019--sysdmdbpageinfo/). With the caveat that this is a pretty expensive query, and you may want to filter it down further to limit the output to just the specific rows in `sys.dm_tran_locks` you are investigating:

   ```
   SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id), OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id), * 
   FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS t
   INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL,'LIMITED') AS p
   ON t.resource_associated_entity_id = CASE 
     WHEN resource_type = N'OBJECT' THEN p.object_id
     WHEN resource_type IN (N'KEY',N'PAGE',N'RID') THEN p.rowset_id 
     -- not quite sure about EXTENT
   END
   WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(p.object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0;
   ```
2. Yes, `resource_associated_entity_id` is the `object_id`, when the resource_type is `OBJECT`. For other resource types, it is going to reference other types of identifiers, like `rowset_id` or `allocation_unit_id`. This is why the column isn't simply named `object_id`.
3. `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id);` will return the object name, regardless of whether the `object_id` is negative or positive. [#temp tables have negative `object_id` values](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/09/sql-server-v-next-denali-breaking-change-to-temp-tables), for example, in SQL Server 2012 and up, and really there is no guarantee that any `object_id` will be positive.